# Calling journalctl from Java

Tags: java, linux, centos

When I run the following command as the root user in the Centos 7 Linux terminal, it produces 57 lines of output:

```
journalctl --output=json-pretty UNIT=firewalld.service
```

So how do I change the code below to successfully call this from Java without having to leave my password in a file?

Here is my attempt.  When I execute the following code, the console only outputs `exit: 1`:

```
String s;
Process p;
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("journalctl --output=json-pretty UNIT=firewalld.service");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println("line: " + s);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
    p.destroy();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

### Edit

When I add the following:

```
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
while ((s = br2.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("error line: " + s);
```

The following output gets generated:

```
error line: No journal files were found.
error line: Failed to get realtime timestamp: Cannot assign requested address
```

Is the problem related to permissions?  When I run `journalctl --output=json-pretty UNIT=firewalld.service` as `root` from the Linux terminal, I get the 57 lines of output.  But when I run `journalctl --output=json-pretty UNIT=firewalld.service` as a normal user, the terminal tells me that no files were found.  I do not want to put my root password in Java code.

Is there some other way to call `journalctl` from Java without having to leave the system root password in a file?

Comment: An exit status of `1` indicates an error. You should read the error stream (`p.getErrorStream()`), it will probably contain the error message. It would be helpful if you shared it. Are you running the java program from command line?

Comment: You just printed the Stream object. I meant you have to read it - it's an `InputStream`, you need to open a `BufferedReader` and print each line to `System.out` or something.

Comment: Your best option until CentOS aligns their documentation with reality is to do `sudo chmod og+s /usr/bin/journalctl` to allow a normal user to use journalctl. Neither adding to systemd-journal (as per the man page), nor adding to `adm` as per [pid-eins](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journalctl.html) works on CentOS 7

Comment: The `grep` should work with this change is that not emough to get the list of units that write in the logs?

Comment: I also updated my answer with the insights of RealSkeptic, that now allows me to journalctl as a normal, that is only a member of systemd-journal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the manual page for `journalctl` tells you that adding a user to `systemd-journal` should allow them to access all journals, that doesn't work on CentOS 7. I have initially worked around this by doing:

```
chmod +s /usr/bin/journalctl
```

**But that gives everyone access to the journals and that might not be what you want**.

As @RealSkeptic pointed out the `man` page for `systemd-journald.service` indicates that additional access rights can be given to groups to read the journal (and states as well that adding a user to `systemd-journal` should be enough). Combining that information you can do

```
sudo setfacl -Rnm g:systemd-journal:rx,d:g:systemd-journal:rx /run/log/journal/
```

and after that adding the user to the `systemd-journal` group, as per the man pages, is enough to allow access to the journals:

```
sudo usermod -a -G systemd-journal your_user_name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add your (normal) user to the group `systemd-journal` using `usermod -a -G systemd-journal <username>`. Logout and login to it for the change to take effect. This gives your user access to the system journal files without giving it complete root privileges.

The group may be different for different operating system setups. You can simply take a look at which group the journal files belong to, by using `ls -l /var/log/journal/` or `ls -l /run/systemd/journal/` if `/var/log/journal/` does not exist.

I have tried this in Centos LiveCD, and the group the files belonged to was `root`. So you can add the user to group `root`, which is *not* the same as giving it full root permissions.

Nevertheless, I suppose a better route to go would be to set ACLs on the journal files to allow a particular group to access them, because the `root` group may have access to a little bit too much. The manual for `systemd-journald.service` gives this example ACL modification command, that grants read access to the journal to `wheel` and `adm`:

```sh
setfacl -Rnm g:wheel:rx,d:g:wheel:rx,g:adm:rx,d:g:adm:rx /var/log/journal/
```

Comment: That is what the manual page says, but that doesn't work on CentOS 7 (and neither does adding to group `adm` as per [pid-eins](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journalctl.html). If you have this working on which kind of system?

Comment: @Anthon I have researched this a little bit and added to my answer. Although yours has been accepted, I think you may find the information useful (or you may wish to further critique it).

Comment: My answer is not elegant, it just works (and I understand what it does ;-) ). Your approach is better although it doesn't exactly solved the problems on CentOS 7, it pointed in the right direction (I have to read up on setfacl).